# Speed up Springboot startup time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

There is a springboot application which uses Oracle with JPA, Swagger, external http connections via RestTemplates etc; and it taken around 60 seconds to startup.

I have referred number of posts related to this and one of the suggestions was to exclude unwanted Autoconfigs (suitable for production deployments).

I tried excluding unwanted AutoConfigs listed below, but did not result in any speed improvements.

- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.AutoServiceRegistrationAutoConfiguration
- org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudAutoConfiguration
- org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudServiceCallConfigurationAutoConfiguration
- org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudServiceChooserAutoConfiguration
- org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudServiceDiscoveryAutoConfiguration
- org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudServiceFilterAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration

I have removed those and pasted the log below (debug log is [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/cccf2a98)) so that someone can help me in improving the speed.

I am interested in knowing some suggestions or approaches to try out.

Thanks in advance.

```
[user@localhost target]$ java -jar myproject-service-1.1.0.jar
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/myproject/target/myproject-service-1.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/myproject/target/myproject-service-1.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
23:52:21.432 [main] INFO org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector - Kotlin reflection implementation not found at runtime, related features won't be available.
LOGBACK: No context given for c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1239548589

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

23:52:22.389  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .s.m.o.MysserviceMTServiceApplication : Starting MysserviceMTServiceApplication on localhost.localdomain with PID 18349 (/home/myproject/target/myproject-service-1.1.0.jar started by user in /home/myproject/target)
23:52:22.390  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .s.m.o.MysserviceMTServiceApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (jar:file:/home/myproject/target/myproject-service-1.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/groovy-2.5.9.jar!/) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
23:52:22.954  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
23:52:26.554  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
23:52:26.732  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 137ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
23:52:28.846  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatinservicesConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatinservicesConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3bb6406] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
23:52:28.871  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.xml.DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils      : http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD property not supported by org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
23:52:28.873  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.xml.DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils      : http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema property not supported by org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
23:52:29.066  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
23:52:29.630  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$414d6526] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
23:52:30.242  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log               : Logging initialized @9597ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
23:52:30.398  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyServletWebServerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8089
23:52:30.403  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : jetty-9.4.26.v20200117; built: 2020-01-17T12:35:33.676Z; git: 7b38981d25d14afb4a12ff1f2596756144edf695; jvm 13.0.2+8
23:52:30.482  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
23:52:30.482  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7417 ms
23:52:31.858  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .a.c.c.x.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean : Using custom default ThreadPoolProfile with id: callbackThreadPoolProfile and implementation: org.apache.camel.model.ThreadPoolProfileDefinition@5dda6f9
23:52:32.378  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.i.e.BaseExecutorServiceManager     : Using custom DefaultThreadPoolProfile: ThreadPoolProfile[callbackThreadPoolProfile (true) size:50-50, keepAlive: 60 SECONDS, maxQueue: 250, allowCoreThreadTimeOut:false, rejectedPolicy:CallerRuns]
23:52:34.055  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.c.s.zipkin2.ZipkinAutoConfiguration  : Check result of the [RestTemplateSender{http://zipkinserver:9411/api/v2/spans}] contains an error [CheckResult{ok=false, error=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://zipkinserver:9411/api/v2/spans": zipkinserver; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: zipkinserver}]
23:52:34.683  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
23:52:34.683  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
23:52:34.685  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
23:52:34.696  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@53c99b09{application,/services/mysserviceSend/2_0,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.9286820292333284465.8089/, jar:file:/home/myproject/target/myproject-service-1.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
23:52:34.696  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : Started @14051ms
23:52:34.964  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
23:52:35.135  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
23:52:35.495  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
23:52:35.722  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
23:52:36.652  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
23:52:36.700  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
23:52:47.618  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
23:52:47.629  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
23:52:50.417  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
23:52:51.091  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
23:52:53.535  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://www.mycomp.com/wsdl/nservice/mysservice/send/v1_0/interface}sserviceService from class com.mycomp.wsdl.nservice.mysservice.send.v1_0._interface.sservice
23:52:56.918  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
23:52:59.107  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
23:52:59.130  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
23:52:59.131  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
23:52:59.132  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore             : RAMJobStore initialized.
23:52:59.133  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

23:52:59.134  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
23:52:59.134  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
23:52:59.134  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@36349e29
23:52:59.343  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.x.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils  : http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD property not supported by org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
23:52:59.344  WARN [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.x.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils  : http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet property not supported by org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
23:53:00.766  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
23:53:00.813  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
23:53:00.949  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
23:53:01.479  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Starting Quartz Scheduler now
23:53:01.480  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
23:53:01.503  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
23:53:01.504  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mycomp.ase.services.common.components.AseJacksonJsonProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
23:53:08.795  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 3.0.0-M4 (CamelContext: sserviceCamelContext) is starting
23:53:08.796  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.management.JmxManagementStrategy   : JMX is enabled
23:53:10.011  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : Setting org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true to ensure QuartzScheduler(s) will be enlisted in JMX.
23:53:10.011  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : Create and initializing scheduler.
23:53:10.016  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
23:53:10.016  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool        : Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
23:53:10.058  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
23:53:10.059  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
23:53:10.059  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore             : RAMJobStore initialized.
23:53:10.067  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-sserviceCamelContext' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

23:53:10.068  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-sserviceCamelContext' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
23:53:10.068  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
23:53:10.498  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl       : Setting the server's publish address to be http://0.0.0.0:8090/api/myproject
23:53:10.749  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint    : Job mysservicePurger.every5secs (triggerType=CronTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is Thu Oct 08 23:55:00 IST 2020
23:53:10.839  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.i.e.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy   : StreamCaching in use with spool directory: /tmp/camel/camel-tmp-27359073-c092-4b62-aba9-6dfde734427f and rules: [Spool > 128K body size]
23:53:10.859  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : jetty-9.4.26.v20200117; built: 2020-01-17T12:35:33.676Z; git: 7b38981d25d14afb4a12ff1f2596756144edf695; jvm 13.0.2+8
23:53:10.905  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started ServerConnector@1edf52e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8090}
23:53:10.906  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : Started @50260ms
23:53:10.908  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@65b1693c{/api,null,AVAILABLE}
23:53:10.909  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: cxfrs://bean:cxfEndpoint?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer
23:53:10.911  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route2 started and consuming from: direct://getServiceDefinition
23:53:10.912  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route3 started and consuming from: direct://callbackHandlerRoute
23:53:10.914  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: MyApiv2mysservicemysserviceRoute started and consuming from: direct://MyApiv2mysservice:mysservice://mysserviceSend
23:53:10.919  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route4 started and consuming from: quartz://mysservicePurger/every5secs?cron=0+0%2F05+*+*+*+%3F
23:53:10.953  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://www.mycomp.com/wsdl/nservice/mysservice/notification/v1_0/interface}mysserviceNotification from class com.mycomp.wsdl.nservice.mysservice.notification.v1_0._interface.mysserviceNotification
23:53:11.048  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl       : Setting the server's publish address to be http://0.0.0.0:9670/mysserviceDeliveryReceipt/nservice
23:53:11.050  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : jetty-9.4.26.v20200117; built: 2020-01-17T12:35:33.676Z; git: 7b38981d25d14afb4a12ff1f2596756144edf695; jvm 13.0.2+8
23:53:11.059  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started ServerConnector@15afebcc{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9670}
23:53:11.059  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : Started @50414ms
23:53:11.060  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@672f69f7{/mysserviceDeliveryReceipt,null,AVAILABLE}
23:53:11.060  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: mysserviceNotification started and consuming from: cxf://bean:mysserviceNotificationEndpoint
23:53:11.062  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: MyApimysserviceNotificationSubRoute started and consuming from: direct://MyApimysserviceNotificationSubRoute
23:53:11.062  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 7 routes, of which 7 are started
23:53:11.067  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 3.0.0-M4 (CamelContext: sserviceCamelContext) started in 2.268 seconds
23:53:11.072  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.a.c.component.quartz.QuartzComponent   : Starting scheduler.
23:53:11.072  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler-sserviceCamelContext_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
23:53:11.218  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
23:53:11.219  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
23:53:11.290  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 71 ms
23:53:11.290  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring MessageDispatcherServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet'
23:53:11.290  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.w.t.http.MessageDispatcherServlet    : Initializing Servlet 'messageDispatcherServlet'
23:53:11.299  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
23:53:11.344  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.w.t.http.MessageDispatcherServlet    : Completed initialization in 54 ms
23:53:11.362  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started ServerConnector@4fad6218{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8089}
23:53:11.364  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] o.s.b.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer  : Jetty started on port(s) 8089 (http/1.1) with context path '/services/mysserviceSend/2_0'
23:53:11.403  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .s.m.o.MysserviceMTServiceApplication : Started MysserviceMTServiceApplication in 49.896 seconds (JVM running for 50.757)
23:53:11.410  INFO [M,,,] 18349 --- [m] .s.m.o.MysserviceMTServiceApplication : TLS has been disabled
```

Comment: Just randomly excluding configuration won't help. Measure what takes the longest time to start and fix that (the auto config is pretty smart and fast in excluding classes it might shave of a few ms not seconds). Generally it is the database/jpa setup that is taking too long, generally due to bad configuration of that config, leading to detection of metadata which is slow on certain databases.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, jpa part is taking around 13 seconds as per the INFO log pasted above. However I am not quite clear which configurations I can change, any thoughts? My app is supporting different versions of Oracle (like 11g, 18c as well as 19c) in different deployment...
I am not exactly clear how to figure out which AutoConfigs must be removed even though I randomly picked from "Positive matches" list; any suggestions?

Comment: you want to do this on production or dev/locally?

Comment: @wak786 this is for production, we want to improve the startup time of the services in production environment.

Comment: excluding those configs won't help you much, as those are milliseconds. THe main one is probably JPA and your datasource setup. Make sure that there is as little metadata usage needed by specifying the correct dialect and add `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false` to the list of properties for jpa (`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false`) which reduces the usage of metadata. I would also suggest to upgrade to the latest Spring Boot 2.2.x version which has some improvements as well. Finally please add your configuration file to the question.

Comment: Another thing to slightly, improve performance is to include the `spring-context-indexer` as an optional dependency. It will, whilst building, create an index of all beans which will be reused at startup of the application, reducing the time needed to scan the classpath.

Comment: And another is to add `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=DEFERRED` to your config, this will, slightly delay the Spring Data JPA setup.

Comment: Looking at your logs there is also an error in your logging setup, you might want to fix that as well (detecting things and throwing errors is relativly slow). It also appears you have JMX enabled, do you really need JMX? If not disable it `spring.jmx.enabled=false` although that should already be the default, you might want to tune Apache Camel as well.

Comment: With all this in mind, change this,t ry again and see if it helps. Next please add your configuration (properties) and `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class (and any other `@Configuration` classes you might have).

Comment: Do not use Camel `3.0.0-M4`. This is preview version not meant for production use, and there are many known implementations, which are really slow. This have been improved a lot in actual versions.

Comment: @Bedla - sure, thanks for pointing that out, I will change it.

Comment: @M.Deinum - sure, I will try these points and get back with the findings.

Comment: @lkamal did you see any improvement, especially on db initializing part?